# Are there any “Third Order” acronyms used in space exploration?

Tags: terminology

On a [recent episode](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/planetary-radio/show/2019/0911-2019-carr-fenimore-los-alamos.html) of the Planetary Radio podcast, the topic of Third-Order Acronyms was brought up. At NASA, there are many Second-order acronyms like SAFER - Simplified Aid For EVA Rescue, where there is an acronym inside of an acronym. Are there any acronyms inside of acronyms inside of acronyms  (Third Order) used in space exploration?

EDIT: Initialisms are also accepted.

Comment: It's 48 minutes long, can you mention roughly where to start listening? I've often wished we had some special mechanism for puzzler questions or Space Golf (similar to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)) and this would be a great candidate! Another example: [Rockets with n-engines, for n = 1, 2, 3…](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23860/12102) you can see how many people participated before it was unilaterally shut-down :-(

Comment: Acronyms are a dime a dozen at NASA. I vaguely recall running across a fourth order acronym at some point in my career, but the recollection is vague. All I remember was "Wow. A fourth order acronym."

Comment: I know of plenty of (often jocular) infinite-order acronyms.  Not necessarily specific to space exploration, but possibly used by some people at NASA.  Linux developers seem to love them, e.g. "PINE": "PINE Is Not ELM", or "GIMP": "GIMP Is Mainly Photoshop", etc.  (I'm aware they have other meanings, Linux people are just like that sometimes.)  Then there was Dilbert's "The TTP Project", where the second 'T' stands for "The TTP Project".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman GIMP is a double-infinite acronym! GIMP is also named GNU Image Manipulation Program, where GNU is “GNU’s Not Unix”

Comment: Space acronym trivia; https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~gpetitpas/Links/Astroacro.html includes gems such as "Bright Infrared Galaxy All Sky Survey"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Googling `"GIMP Is Mainly Photoshop"` returns exactly one result: your comment.

Comment: @CourageousPotato: Also: `It's time [to] explain the meaning of "Hurd". "Hurd" stands for "Hird of Unix-Replacing Daemons". And, then, "Hird" stands for "Hurd of Interfaces Representing Depth". We have here, to my knowledge, the first software to be named by a pair of mutually recursive acronyms.` See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Hurd).

Comment: @EricDuminil Hmm.  I saw a few more results under "Mostly" instead of "Mainly".  Obviously these things are totally unofficial, spread through word of mouth.  Not sure how to do a search for "GIMP Is <some word that starts with 'M'> Photoshop".

Comment: Double infinite... That's the point where mathematicians get curious...

Comment: @EricDuminil Nice: That statement became wrong in the moment you posted it because it is right.

Comment: @EricDuminil Please avoid code formatting for quotations or highlights; because it indicates “text for a computer rather than a person,” alternative browsing technologies (e.g. screen readers for the blind) have to try to render it in a way that would be intelligible as code—reading letter-by-letter is not unheard of, for example. Quotation marks, or bold or italics formatting, do their jobs quite well.

Answer (score 80):

Yes.

- NUTI => NASCOM User Traffic Interface
- NASCOM => NASA Communications
- NASA => National Aeronautics and Space Administration

Found by parsing this list of over [14,000 NASA acronyms](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/acronyms.cgi?program=shuttle&searchall=true)

It also contains a vast number of second order acronyms, but the example above is the only third order acronym I could find through initial analysis.

Comment: That's 14,000 Shuttle acronyms. It isn't a complete list of Shuttle-related acronyms, and it's only Shuttle-related acronyms.

Comment: @DavidHammen One black swan disproves the "all swans are white" fallacy. The question asks "are there any", this shows there are.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think David was taking issue with it being described as "NASA acronyms" when it is only a subset of Shuttle acronyms, but if so I'm not sure that hair splitting is relevant. The list *is* NASA acronyms, it just so happens to be a subset of NASA acronyms that only includes Shuttle acronyms.

Comment: By the way, if you change "program=shuttle" to "program=station" in the URL, you got a long list of some Space Station acronyms.

Answer (score 47):

I gave an example of one a while back in this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/what-is-the-evolved-expendable-launch-vehicle-eelv-secondary-payload-adapter/26716#26716):

[image]

Alternate version by [Magic Octopus Urn](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/25224/magic-octopus-urn)

[image]

Alternate version by [Eric Duminil](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/19229/eric-duminil)

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to draw this diagram that isn't a little bit confusing?

Comment: Knock yourself out!

Comment: @Hohmannfan  I guess if I had drawn it with the 1st acronym at the bottom and run the arrows up, I could have listed the words in forward instead of reverse order.  That might have been a better choice.  Odds of me redoing it are slim though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble. Make the arrows go left

Comment: @MadPhysicist that would work too. I'm too top-down, left-to-right biased apparently.

Comment: Feel free to use this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsZFo.png) if you think it's better.

Comment: @Hohmannfan the diagram looks perfectly understandable to me, and quite clever.

Comment: ‮ sey tub eht sdrow era ni esrever redro

Comment: @Hohmannfan That comment is really clever! How'd you reverse the order of _everything_?

Comment: Evolved Expendable Launch Vehicle Secondary Payload Adapter Augmented Geosynchronous Laboratory Experiment? EELVSPAAGLE. Oof, that gave me a headache trying to figure out.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AX69B0C.png I made another version of the diagram, dunno if it's objectively "better".

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I like that one, will add to answer if that's OK.

Comment: @EricDuminil added your diagram to answer, hope that's OK.

Comment: @OrganicMarble sure, that's why I proposed it.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: The presentation is fine, but I'd expect the arrows to be reversed. Maybe that's just me, I always complain that the arrows in [UML diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) are pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: @EricDuminil Honestly I think I should've done it 1st, 2nd, 3rd. But I already closed the draw.io page I did it on.

Comment: I did one final one with Eric's notes, I found how to reopen the diagram to make edits, I think he's right it's more clear: https://i.imgur.com/NbiaeXD.png

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: It seems more logical that way, yes.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn updated answer!

Answer (score 19):

While not exactly space exploration there is at least one fourth order acronym for NASA earth observation systems (mostly earth sensing satellites).

- EPR     - EED2 Program Roadmap
- EED     - EOSDIS Evolution and Development
- EOSDIS  - Earth Observation System(EOS) Data and Information System
- EOS     - Earth Observing System

[NASA - EOSDIS Acronym List](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/learn/user-resources/acronym-list#ed-acronym-e)

Comment: Is the last step really an expansion though?

Comment: That’s just a third order - EOS is already expanded in EOSDIS.

Comment: It kind of is, because "Earth Observation System Data and Information System" is lousy grammar, but "EOS Data and Information System" where "EOS" is a proper noun works nicely. So it really kind of "wants" to be unexpanded at the third level.

Answer (score 6):

There's a conference about satellite sounders called the

ITSC: [**I**nternational **T**OVS **S**tudy **C**onference](https://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/itwg/itsc/)

organised by the

ITWG: **I**nternational **T**OVS **W**orking **G**roup

where

TOVS: **T**IROS **O**perational **V**ertical **S**ounder

where

TIROS: **T**elevision **I**nfra**r**ed **O**bservation **S**atellite

Comment: any thoughts on [Modelling point spectrometer energy to weigh DTM facets for spectral mapping](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44778/12102)? (was posted in Astronomy, now in Space SE)

Answer (score 3):

VERITAS mission to Venus (proposed).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VERITAS_(spacecraft)

VERITAS - Venus  Emissivity, Radio science, InSAR,  Topography And Spectroscopy

InSAR - Intrerferometric Synthetic Aperture Radar

Radar - Radio Detection And Ranging