# Was "Apollo" an acronym for "America’s Program for Orbiting Lunar and Landing Operations"?

Tags: apollo-program, history, terminology, united-states

I came across [this paper](https://amostech.com/TechnicalPapers/2018/Astrodynamics/Hinga.pdf) which, on page 9, says the following:

> The guidance or “shooting” algorithm is based on the Linear Peturbation Theory (Battin) developed for the **A**merica’s **P**rogram for **O**rbiting **L**unar and **L**anding **O**perations (APOLLO) program during the 1960s.

Now, I can't tell whether the APOLLO program referenced in this sentence is *the* Apollo program (the one that landed people on the moon in 1969-1972).  Is this sentence referring to a different APOLLO program than the one I thought of when I saw the word Apollo?  If not, was the name of *the* Apollo program really an acronym as indicated in the quoted sentence?

Comment: In the US (unlike [elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/488580/217285)) acronyms should have each letter that comes from the acronymed phrase capitalized. Since Apollo is not, perhaps we'd have to call it a "covert acronym" :-)

Comment: not exactly related but interesting to space acronymologists: [Are there any “Third Order” acronyms used in space exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38771/12102)

Comment: If that were the case, what were MERCURY & GEMINI acronyms for?

Comment: That sounds like the kind of backronyms that you encounter in giant robot anime.

Comment: Wait! So,... the Saturn V actually was a giant samurai robot? It's all starting to make sense now!

Comment: Interestingly @uhoh, the BBC capitalise ESA, but not Nasa. It's how they throw shade.

Comment: @JCRM ha! Yes, and it seem the BBC capitalise BBC as well! :-)

Comment: There is a growing convention that you upper case only the first letter of an acronym, if it is pronounced as a word, thus Nasa ("Nassa") and Nato ('Nayto'). ESA is not an acronym, but it is an initialism (we don't say 'eesa'). Likewise BBC.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: But Nasa, like scuba, radar, laser, and many others, is an acronym that has become a word, often with the origin as an acronym forgotten by most.

Comment: the BBC *do* say [ee-sah](https://youtu.be/bAEEEL8-jBM?t=90) @MichaelHarvey (but they do always say European Space Agency for the first mention, which they don't for Nasa)

Comment: Saying ee-sah should really be avoided as much as possible as it's impossible to do without conjuring up images of Jar-Jar Binks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've always pronounced ESA as "essa" (rather than "eesa") as it seemed natural after having heard "NASA" pronounced "nassa". (Then again, I pronounce many words strangely which I have only seen written and never heard spoken, much to the bemusement of people I'm speaking with.)

Comment: Meta-comment: The difference, and overlap, between "Initialisms" and "Acronyms" is useful to know. Also worth noting, there's no one *definitive version* of English. The real question here is: Acronym Vs Backronym.

Comment: If it were an acronym, it would make more sense if it were "... orbiting and landing lunar operations", I think.

Comment: I wonder if this was a poorly delivered bit of humor on the part of the author.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From [a pre-launch press release for Apollo 11](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/history/apollo_press_release.html):

> Among the many missions conceived at that time was a manned journey to the Moon and back. Dr. Silverstein himself named it "Apollo" after one of the most versatile of the Greek gods. Dr. Silverstein recalls he chose the name after perusing a book of mythology at home one evening, early in 1960. He thought that the image of "Apollo riding his chariot across the Sun was appropriate to the grand scale of the proposed program."

So named after the Greek god, and absolutely not an acronym.

Comment: also - when the project was named, they didn't even know if they were going to do direct, lunar orbit or earth orbit rendevous, so having "lunar orbit" in the name before they even knew the plan is silly

Comment: Apollo wasn’t even conceived specifically as a lunar landing project.

Answer (score 27):

There's currently a single [Google](https://google.com/?q=%22America%E2%80%99s+Program+for+Orbiting+Lunar+and+Landing+Operations%22)<sup>1</sup> hit for that phrase<sup>2</sup>, so I strongly suspect this is a backronym the author thought was clever.

It might be worth checking the reference given around this information "Battin, R. H., [An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0930403258), American Insitute of Aeronautics and Astrodynamics,1987."<sup>3</sup>  -- although [dronir](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/34987/dronir) noted in the comments that "Google books' search inside" doesn't find  the phrase.

In the comments, [T.E.D.](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/30014/t-e-d) pointed out that in technical documents acronyms tend to be defined the first time they are used, and various lists of acronyms exist, so there would be no be trouble whatsoever finding evidence if it were really an acronym.

Also, [Austin Hemmelgarn](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/20875/austin-hemmelgarn) pointed out that (especially in the Apollo ERA) acronyms were given in all-caps or small-caps, and goes on to say they weren't able to find all-caps APOLLO (except in contexts where all text would be in all-caps anyway, such as title pages and mission patches)

---

<sup>1</sup> Other search engines are available

<sup>2</sup> The hit was this question

<sup>3</sup> Other booksellers are available

Comment: Adding to this, the only places I can find 'APOLLO' in all-caps that's actually from the project itself are the project insignia and the mission patches, but those use all-caps or small caps for everything on them, so they can't really be taken as evidence of it being an acronym.

Comment: Google books' search inside that reference does not seem to contain any mention of that "acronym".

Comment: agreed it is a backronym. I've seen it on something fairly old but am away from home atm

Comment: FWIW, I've done a fair bit of military and some NASA contract work. If a word is an acronym, its required to define it once, and usually to put it in an appendix of acronyms, in *any document dealing with it*. So if it were really an acronym, I'm quite confident that we'd not be having any trouble whatsoever finding evidence.

Comment: Now that it became HNQ, that Google query points to loads and loads of SE pages. I wonder what that lonely hit was...

Answer (score 11):

Some early rocket programs:

- Mercury
- Gemini
- Saturn
- Apollo
- Atlas
- Thor
- Juno
- Athena
- Jupiter

There's a definite naming pattern...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Just because NASA uses a naming theme doesn't mean that they don't also acronym or backronym those names.  That's commonly done at NASA now.

Comment: "Man's Greatest Space Achievements Attained Thanks to Johnson And Johnson"   we're onto you Illuminati !    (humour)

Comment: It doesn't explicitly answer the question but it does strongly hint at it ... there aren't well known acronyms for all the others, even if you can invent plausible backronyms for one or two.

Answer (score 2):

## Absolutely not

[***Origins of NASA Names***](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19770010038), SP-4402, is the 242-page official NASA history of the names of launch vehicles, spacecraft, manned spaceflight programs, sounding rockets, and NASA field installations.  The entry for *Apollo* is three pages long and makes no mention of it being an acronym.  Notably:

> Abe Silverstein, Director of Space Flight Development, proposed the name "Apollo" because it was the name of a god in ancient Greek mythology with attractive connotations and the precedent for naming manned spaceflight projects for mythological gods and heroes had been set with Mercury.  Apollo was god of archery, prophecy, poetry, and music, and most significantly he was god of the sun.  In his horse-drawn golden chariot, Apollo pulled the sun in its course across the sky each day.  NASA approved the name and publicly announced "Project Apollo" at the July 28-29 conference.

Furthermore, **Apollo does not appear in Appendix A of the *Origins of NASA Names*, which lists every abbreviation and acronym.**  It is therefore not an acronym.